# Commits from the branch checked out off appears in a checked-branch after the merge. Why?

Tags: git, github, merge

Why am I seeing commits from a different branch `A` in branch `B` after branch `A` has been squashed-merged into `main`?

Following is a sequence of steps performed:

```
git branch                    // "A" (current branch)
git checkout -b B             // create B out of A
// make some commits to B

git checkout A
// make some commits to A

git checkout B
git pull --rebase origin A    // get latest commits from A in B
// resolve merge conflicts in B

// A gets squash-merged to main via GitHub


git pull --rebase origin main // get latest commits from main in B had to resolve 
                                 conflicts again in B which was a surprise

git log // B contains commits from branch A 
           which I'd expect to vanish after the merge
```

Answer (score 0):

`B` doesn't know that `A` ever existed, nor does the squash-commit in `main` know what commits were squashed to create it. All of the commits added to `B` (both "directly" and from rebasing onto `A`) look identical to git now.  You've ended up with a branch `B` that is `N` commits ahead of the original point, and `main` that is 1 commit ahead of the original point. When you rebase `B` onto the udpated main, you get exactly those `N+1` unique commits.

To avoid this, don't rebase onto commits that aren't going to be part of the "permanent" history of the repo.

Comment: But `B` was created out of `A` and `B` does know `main` exists no? So if commits from each feature branch is squash-merged to main are squashed, there's no point rebasing? What's the way out now? Manually cherry pick commits in `B` in a separate clean branch?

Comment: @xyf Branches don't know that other branches exist because branches "don't exist" in the first place. Branches are just temporary pointers to commits. It's the commits that matter.

Comment: So I guess it's only safe to rebase on top of `main` since it contains squashed-commits rather than feature branches. What's the way out?

Comment: @xyf That sounds like a safe strategy. You might be able to get away with messier commits in the feature branches if they are going to be ultimately squash as well. You can also use `git rebase -i` at anytime to rewrite / fix the history of your feature branch. Just be careful whenever you rewrite histories that have already been pushed to other repos

Comment: What's the solution for getting commits from `A` in `B` given `B` is supposed to be on top of `A` while both branches are in progress/not merged to main?

Comment: Cherry picking is probably the simplest way to recover. You might also be able to recover the original commits from `B` prior to rebasing from the reflog, and rebase those onto `main`.